# Dynamic List Boxes with DrawItem event for each one of them

Tags: c#, dynamic, listbox, event-handling, draw

I'm creating a TabControl that contains on each of it's dynamically created TabPage a dynamically created ListBox, each of them with a different content.
For each ListBox I want to handle the text that goes inside (changing it's color depending on a state which is not visible in the shown code).

At the moment I'm coloring the text for a specific ListBox by using a class that holds the color of the text and the message that will be used for a row.

Example with the code used for the manually created ListBox:

```
    private void listBoxLogs_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        ListBoxLogsItem item = listBoxLogs.Items[e.Index] as ListBoxLogsItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            e.DrawBackground();

            e.Graphics.DrawString(item.m_message, listBoxLogs.Font, item.m_color, e.Bounds, System.Drawing.StringFormat.GenericDefault);

            System.Drawing.Graphics g = listBoxLogs.CreateGraphics();
            System.Drawing.SizeF s = g.MeasureString(item.m_message, listBoxLogs.Font);

            if (s.Width > listBoxLogs.HorizontalExtent)
            {
                listBoxLogs.HorizontalExtent = (int)s.Width + 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

The following code is used to create the TabPage and the ListBox:

```
    // _tagName is an identifier used to know the TabPage and ListBox in which the text will be added
    private void AddTabPage(string _tagName)
    {
        ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
        listBox.Text = _tagName;
        listBox.Name = _tagName;
        listBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 6);
        listBox.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
        listBox.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.listBoxLogs_DrawItem);
        listBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(628, 378);
        listBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
        listBox.HorizontalScrollbar = true;
        listBox.ItemHeight = 17;
        listBox.TabIndex = 15;

        // TODO: Remove this line. Added just for testing
        listBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxLogsItem(System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, ""));

        TabPage tab = new TabPage();
        tab.Name = _tagName;
        tab.Controls.Add(listBox);

        // Add the TabPage to the TabControl only when it's available
        ExecuteOnControlThread(delegate
        {
            tabControl.Controls.Add(tab);
        });
    }
```

I can not figure out how to identify the ListBox that calls the DrawItemEventHandler "this.listBoxLogs_DrawItem".

Can somebody please tell me how I can do this, or a different way that will allow me to get the same result ?

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking, but you can identify them via reference, or set ListBox.Name. Can you tell in which way you want identify them? the passed paramter 'sender' is your ListBox. Just cast it to ListBox à la 
`var anyListBox = (ListBox)sender;`

Comment: Thank you @Bagerfahrer 

That's the thing that I've missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sender` is the control that raised the event you're handling. When you created the handler in the Properties grid, what was the selected control? The ListBox. So that's the control raising the event.

```
private void listBoxLogs_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lbSender = (ListBox)sender;

    // ...other stuff
}
```

In general, stick a breakpoint in the handler method and examine the parameters at runtime when the event is raised. That's always a quick way to get your bearings with these things.

Comment: Thank you @Ed

I don't know why I didn't look into sender ... I've seen it's displayed value in Watch is {SelectedItem = ""} and didn't think to look furred.